# Python set: "empty" element, incorrect input

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I can't understand how it works.
I have input of :

```
10 2 3 4 8
```

And simple code

```
b = set(input())
print(b)
```

Returns:

```
{' ', '3', '1', '2', '8', '0', '4'}
```

Why I'm getting this `' '` el. and how to get 10 instead of `'1'` and `'0'` ?

Comment: `input` returns a string with spaces between numbers, you need to split it

Comment: `set` looks at each character in the sequence.

Comment: You'd need to [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) the string, returned by `input`, at the spaces to get a `list` of separate words (in this case numbers, but not integers, they're still strings). `input().split()`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Again!

Answer (score 2):

`set()` takes an iterable (such as list, tuple, dict, etc.) and makes a set of its items.  For example:

```
x = [4, 5, 6]
y = set(x)
print(y)
#set([4, 5, 6])
```

A string is iterable, too:

```
for char in "yay":
    print(char)

#Output:
y
a
y
```

Therefore, a set can convert a string:

```
x = "yay there"
y = set(x)
print(y)
#set(['a', ' ', 'e', 'h', 'r', 't', 'y'])
```

If you want each word, use [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
b = set(input().split())
```

Comment: you really want `b = set(map(int, input().split()))` if you want to get the integers

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` with a `lambda` function to remove the space elements:

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x is not " ", [" ", "1", "2", " "])
>>> ['1', '2']
```